# Gravar fk logo após a pk ser gerada com entity

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

Tenho um sistema e nesse sistema tem algumas tabelas que são associativas. Assim que eu gravo no BD a tabela principal, preciso garantir que aquela nova PK gerada, seja gravada em outras três tabelas, mas tem que garantir que é aquela gerada. O sistema roda na web e isso precisa ser evitado que outra pessoa esteja usando a mesma rotina e dispare outra PK, entede?

Aqui gero a PK que será FK nas outras tabelas

```
[HttpPost]
public void GravaResponsavel(string _responsavel, bool _ativo)
        { 
            using(RupturaEntities db = new RupturaEntities())
            {
                Responsavel resp = new Responsavel();
                try
                {
                    resp.NM_Responsavel = _responsavel;
                    resp.Ativo = _ativo;
                    db.Responsavel.Add(resp);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {}
            }
        }
```

Comment: Não entendo muito de entity, mas tenta assim; Depois do `db.SaveChanges();`, adiciona um `var id = resp.id;` pra pegar o último ID inserido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No fim de gravares, ires buscar o `id` da tabela `Responsavel` não te resolve a questão?

```
[HttpPost]
public void GravaResponsavel(string _responsavel, bool _ativo)
{ 
    using(RupturaEntities db = new RupturaEntities())
    {
        Responsavel resp = new Responsavel();
        Tabela1 tbl1 = new Tabela1();
        Tabela2 tbl2 = new Tabela2();
        Tabela3 tbl3 = new Tabela3();
        try
        {
            resp.NM_Responsavel = _responsavel;
            resp.Ativo = _ativo;
            db.Responsavel.Add(resp);
            db.SaveChanges();

            tbl1.id_Responsavel = resp.id;
            tbl2.id_Responsavel = resp.id;
            tbl3.id_Responsavel = resp.id;

            db.Tabela1.add(tbl1);
            db.Tabela2.add(tbl2);
            db.Tabela3.add(tbl3);

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Pensei assim, aí uma pessoa disse que existe recursos no Sql Server que "como se congelasse aquele id", mas não me deu mais nenhuma informação. Se houver simultaneamente dois inserts. Como se comportará? Essa é a minha preocupação.

Comment: O id será sempre incremental, se houver dois inserts simultaneamente duvido que o SQLserver rebente, porque processa um pedido de cada vez. Agora não te posso dar certezas de nada...

Comment: Ok, valeu. Vou por aí também.